# Firefox Scrolling Bug When Changing :after Contents

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I want to change pseudo elements on a container based on its scroll position. I made a jsfiddle to demonstrate the bug I stumbled upon: http://jsfiddle.net/krzncu1k/1/

The `:after`-element shows the current scroll status ("upper half" or "lower half"). Its content changes by toggling the classes `.upper-half` and `.lower-half` based on scroll position:

```css
.upper-half:after {content:'upper half'; top:0;}
.lower-half:after {content:'lower half'; bottom:0;}
```

The corresponding JS:

```js
$wrap.toggleClass('upper-half', isUpper).toggleClass('lower-half', !isUpper);
```

The bug happens when using Firefox and scrolling via dragging the scrollbar (not via mousewheel!). If you drag it and cross the middle (where the class changes from `.upper-half` to `.lower-half`) you suddenly can't drag any further.

Any ideas on why this behavior occurs and how to fix it?

Comment: not an answer per se - looks like `toggleClass` is removing focus/mousedown from the scrollbar in FF, requiring it to be reselected

Comment: Thought the same. So it's a bug?

Comment: it may just be a difference in how FF rationalizes a change to the scrollable content - note `:after` is related to the actual content of the element (it comes after the content, within the tags), so a change (in position) may be deemed to impact the scrollable- losing focus....or it may be a bug :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea why this occurs in Firefox, but I do have a workaround. Create the upper half with `:before`, the lower half with `:after` and hide and show with opacity when the class changes. Might as well throw in a smooth `transition` as well. The bug is prevented because the position is not changing.

(you could also use `display: none` instead of opacity, but it cannot be transitioned)

### Working Example

```js
$(function() {
  var $wrap = $('.wrap'),
    $ul = $('ul'),
    ulHeight = $ul.height();

  $ul.scroll(function(e) {
    var isUpper = (this.scrollTop + ulHeight / 2) / this.scrollHeight <= 0.5;
    $wrap.toggleClass('upper-half', isUpper).toggleClass('lower-half', !isUpper);
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
li {
  font-size: 200%;
}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
.wrap:before,
.wrap:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.3);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  line-height: 40px;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.wrap:before {
  content: 'upper half';
  top: 0;
}
.wrap:after {
  content: 'lower half';
  bottom: 0;
}
.upper-half:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
.lower-half:before {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap upper-half">
  <ul>
    <li>Some</li>
    <li>Random</li>
    <li>Bullet</li>
    <li>Points</li>
    <li>Just</li>
    <li>To</li>
    <li>Make</li>
    <li>This</li>
    <li>Awesome</li>
    <li>List</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>Little</li>
    <li>Longer</li>
    <li>And</li>
    <li>Longer</li>
    <li>And</li>
    <li>Longer</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Works, thank you. I still wonder if this is a bug or not, but at least I now have a way around it.